# Error al utilizar StreamBuilder e InheritedWidget

Tags: flutter, bloc

Estoy aprendiendo mejor el uso del `InheritedWidget` para lo cual sigo el diseño de un curso para realizar unos Slides pero ahí hacen uso del `Provider` para la comunicación entre `Widgets` pero ya que mi intención es aprender a hacerlo sin paquetes, lo intento hacer con Bloc y el uso de `Streams`

### Error

Al utilizar el `StreamBuilder` me da un error al usarlo en un `AnimatedContainer`, anteriormente no me daba error cuando lo utilizaba en un `Row` que es el que contenía a 3 `Container` que ahora son los `AnimatedContainer` que es donde uso el `Stream` y regresa el siguiente error.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building _Dot(dependencies: [MyInheritedWidget]):
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

The relevant error-causing widget was
    _Dot 
lib\…\pages\slideshow_page.dart:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe 
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:139
#4      _StreamBuilderBaseState.initState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:113
#5      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4684
#6      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4520
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building _Dot(dependencies: [MyInheritedWidget]):
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  _Dot
  
lib\…\pages\slideshow_page.dart:32
A RenderFlex overflowed by 199662 pixels on the right.
```

### Mi `InheritedWidget`

```
class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  MyInheritedWidget({@required this.slideBloc, @required this.child});

  final Widget child;
  final SlidesBloc slideBloc;

  static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;
}
```

### SlidesBloc

```
class SlidesBloc {

  int _index = 0;

  final _controllerIndex = StreamController<int>();

  Stream<int> get streamIndex => _controllerIndex.stream;

  void changeIndex(int index){
    _controllerIndex.add(index);
  }


  dispose(){
    _controllerIndex.close();
  }

}
```

### Uso de `InheritedWidget`

```
class SlideshowPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final SlidesBloc _slidesBloc = SlidesBloc();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MyInheritedWidget(
          slideBloc: _slidesBloc,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: _Slides()), _Dots()],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

### Creación de los `Slides` con un `PageView`

```
class __SlidesState extends State<_Slides> {

  PageController _pageController = PageController(); 
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController.addListener(() {
      final slideBloc = MyInheritedWidget.of(context).slideBloc;
      final index = (_pageController.page + 0.5).toInt();
      slideBloc.changeIndex(index);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: [
            _Slide(
              svg: 'assets/svgs/1.svg',
            ),
            _Slide(
              svg: 'assets/svgs/2.svg',
            ),
            _Slide(
              svg: 'assets/svgs/3.svg',
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

### uso del `StreamBuilder`

```
class _Dot extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  const _Dot(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final slideBloc = MyInheritedWidget.of(context).slideBloc;

    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: slideBloc.streamIndex,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final indexStream = snapshot.data;
        return AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          width: index == indexStream? 10:12,
          height: index == indexStream? 10:12,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle, color:index == indexStream?Colors.blue: Colors.grey),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```